# Show that $0 \le (1-t)\alpha + t\beta \le 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $t, \alpha, \beta$ be real numbers, with 
$$0 \le t \le 1$$
$$0 \le \alpha \le 1$$
$$0 \le \beta \le 1$$

I need to show that $$0 \le (1-t)\alpha + t\beta \le 1$$
I am stuck showing that, I got  $$0 \le (1-t)\alpha + t\beta \le \color{red}{2}$$
Could anyone support me with some hints.

Comment: First prove the upper bound $f(\alpha, \beta)$ when $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 1$, then show that $\alpha < 1$ and $\beta < 1$ implies $f(\alpha, \beta) < f(1,1)$

Comment: Consider what happens when t=0, when t=1, and when t is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the maximum of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and try to get a tighter inequality using this, as all the terms are positive.
Can you continue from here ?

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and define $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(t)=(1-t)\alpha+t\beta$. Differentiate $f$, then we get $f'(t)=\beta-\alpha$. If $\beta \ge \alpha$, then $\min f=\alpha$ and $\max f =\beta$, and if $\beta < \alpha$, then $\min f=\beta$ and $\max f=\alpha$. Thus,
$$
0\le\min\{\alpha,\beta\}\le f(t)=(1-t)\alpha+t\beta\le\max\{\alpha,\beta\}\le 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha=\beta$ then $(1-t)\alpha+t\beta=\alpha\leq 1$.

If $\alpha<\beta$ then $(1-t)\alpha+t\beta<(1-t)\beta+t\beta=\beta\leq 1$

Similar for $\beta<\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Geometric viewpoint- $ (1-t)\alpha + t\beta $ divides the segment defined by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the ratio $t:1-t$. Can you see why this point is between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and hence in the interval $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $t\ge 0$, we can multiply $\beta\le 1$ on both sides with $t$ to get $t\beta\le t$. Similarly, we get $(1-t)\alpha\le 1-t$. Therefore we get
$$(1-t)\alpha + t\beta \le (1-t) + t = 1$$